# Odd linked list/anonymous class behavior - executing when added?

Tags: java, linked-list, execution, anonymous-class, first-class-functions

This question is related to [How to Queue and Call Actual Methods..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3019172/how-to-queue-and-call-actual-methods-rather-than-immediately-eval-in-java). Anyway, I've decided to (after all) go with the anonymous class idea. The problem is that when I ADD my anonymous class to the linked list, it's actually calling execute() immediately... and it shouldn't be. Execute() is to be called later. Anyway, this is what I have:

```
private LinkedList<AgentAction> actions;
public boolean blockingSensor;

this.actions.add( new AgentAction(this) {
 public void execute() {
  //setRotationalVelocity(0);
  kinematic.setWheelsVelocity(0,0);
  this.agent.setBlockingSensors(false);
  this.agent.printLCD("Turn, blocking = "+this.agent.blockingSensor);
 }

 public Object getValue() {
  return null;
 }
});

//this is essentially the main()
public void performBehavior()
{
    //make sure to only call run() each tick, not every ms
    if ( this.oldCounter < getCounter() )
    {
        if ( !isWorking() )
        {
            run();
        }
        this.oldCounter = getCounter();
        this.actions.removeFirst().execute();
    }
}

abstract class AgentAction
{
 SimbadAgent agent;
 public AgentAction(SimbadAgent a)
 {
  this.agent = a;
 }
 public abstract void execute();
 public abstract Object getValue();
}
```

run() is an abstract method that is implemented by a child class. I'm just not sure why it's printing when it's added, rather than executed. I understand this would imply that performBehavior() is actually being executed multiple times rather than once per tick, but that's not the case.

Comment: Your sample code isn't going to compile. Can you either make it complete or add some context?

Comment: Hmmm... I don't think the actual code will be of much help, so let's see... There's a class called SimbadAgent in which performBehavior() is inside, as well as the other methods. this.actions.add( new AgentAction(this){...}); is called from within one the methods inside of SimbadAgent. I'm not sure if there's much else I can provide, unfortunately. Sorry if that wasn't any help.

Comment: Let's be clear then.  No, that code doesn't call execute when the action is added.  You're wrong.  The burden is on you to prove otherwise, and you haven't.  Good luck getting free help when you aren't willing to spend time giving us the information we need to help you.  Read over http://sscce.org and give us one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The devil is in the details. There's almost certainly a bug somewhere in the code you're not showing (my guess is `run`), but let's address a deeper point. This code looks a *LOT* like there [producer-consumer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem) problem. If so, I recommend checking out [`java.util.concurrent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html): it's overflowing with concurrency-related goodness that makes things like this *WAY* easier than trying to roll your own. For your particular case, it looks like [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) might be a good fit. If it's not exactly what you need, I still recommend poking around in the package; like I said, it's stuffed with handy things that will probably be a lot easier to work with than something you built yourself from the concurrency primitives.

Comment: Thanks Hank. @Mark Peters My apologies, I'll always have a full example of what my code the next time I post. The program I'm writing is dependent upon a lot of other code and I was in the process of writing a smaller test program to post.

I'm having an.. interesting time making things properly concurrent, but hey I suppose that's why it isn't easy :) Thanks again.